# Total commander rename files in folders

Tags: total-commander

I need rename files in my folders.

**Each foder contain next files:**

1.png

2.png

3.png

**I need to rename as below:**

1.png > a.png

2.png > b.png

3.png > c.png

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I do from the shell prompt to rename a bunch of files in a PictsFolder.

Create a file called rename.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/jscarry/Desktop/PictsFolder
mv 1.png a.png
mv 2.png b.png
exit
```

chmod it to be executable and then run it from the command line.

```
jscarry$ /Users/jscarry/Files/renamePicts.sh
```

Be sure to escape special characters like spaces in your file names.

e.g. File\ Name\ With\ Spaces.png

Answer (score 3):

1. Open desired folder in TotalCmd and select files to rename (Ctrl-A for all files)
2. Press Ctrl-M to open Multi-Rename dialog
3. Fill string "[Ca]" (without quotation marks) into the field "Rename mask file name" and click on button "Start!"

You can replace the letter "a" in string "[Ca]" with any letter or number, and the renaming-sequence will begin with this character (try "[Caaa]" for output files "aaa.png", "aab.png", "aac.png", ...).